# Double brackets not registering in Angular.js html

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I just recently learned angular.js (and i use the word "learned" loosely), and I am trying to make a basic website and have gotten stuck on form validation. I realized that the double bracket notation I learned from "Shaping up with angular.js" isn't registering on the webpage that I have. I've been hacking at this all day and you'll probably see more than a few issues with my code (feel free to comment).

The code piece I am talking about is this:

```
<div class="divvy" ng-repeat="slider in main.sliders">
  <h3>
    {{slider.name}} costs {{slider.cost | currency}}
  </h3>
</div>
```

I will include the entire code, but for reference, the class "divvy" is just a convoluted way to make the div centered on the screen.
My header reads as this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Didact+Gothic|Ek+Mukta|Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  </head>
```

And the script.js file is rather simple, because I haven't really done anything with it yet besides debugging why this isn't working.

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module("myModule",[]);
app.controller('MainController',function(){
  this.products= sliders;
});


var sliders= [

  {name:  "Charles",
    cost:  "4.20"
  },
  {
    name:"Alfred",
    cost:"30"
  },
  {
    name:"Something that costs 10 bucks",
    cost:"10.1"
  }



  ]

  })()
```

Please help me out. I think that something else I was trying to fix made it so that I couldn't use angular properly anymore (there is a button in there that is meant to edit text (also a debugging attempt) and it used to work but no longer does after some ctrl+z made me lose my place).
Additionally, if you have extra time, there is a background picture which I spent a lot of time figuring out how to center and make it "zoom-proof", but I would like to edit it dynamically (background changes with slides or fadechanges) but the background img is stuck in style.css html{}... And I don't know how to edit that using "myStyle" or even use ng-myStyle in the first place. Thank you. The full code is at plunker, here: https://plnkr.co/edit/H4uhcU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be,

```
<div class="divvy" ng-repeat="slider in main.products">
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("myModule",[]);
app.controller('MainController',function(){
  var sliders= [
  {name:  "Charles",
    cost:  "4.20"
  },
  {
    name:"Alfred",
    cost:"30"
  },
  {
    name:"Something that costs 10 bucks",
    cost:"10.1"
  }];

  this.products= sliders;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app= "myModule" ng-controller="MainController as main">
<div class="divvy" ng-repeat="slider in main.products">
  <h3>
    {{slider.name}} costs {{slider.cost | currency}}
  </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, this isn't working for me. I don't know what the problem is, but I've taken out most of the code that wasn't directly related and have put it in "readme" ;; 
I've uploaded the new plunker:  https://plnkr.co/edit/H4uhcU

Comment: you have not refered script.js in the plunker. check here https://plnkr.co/edit/Y7YhbX?p=preview

Comment: It works now, the problem was that the script.js reference was BEFORE the google api script reference. Thanks :)

Comment: One more thing: I have the ng-repeat="slider in main.products"> but after putting the code back in the html file it no longer repeats. Here is the plunk, if you'd be willing to help me one more time:https://plnkr.co/edit/H4uhcU